# Can we get finger print from tablet using c#

Tags: c#

I am facing some problems. I am not sure about that we can get finger print from tablet using C#.If anyone now about that then tell me please.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: i want to scan my finger print through tablet.after scanning my finger print i want to check is it valid or not like that biometric system.

Answer (score 0):

You may check this post to see how to do verification on finger print via C#

[A-Framework-in-C-for-Fingerprint-Verification](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97590/A-Framework-in-C-for-Fingerprint-Verification)

Or **if you want to use the fingerprint device of your tablet**, then you need the  `SDK` for your fingerprint device. You can get it from your vendor, if they are ready to provide you.

For example if your tablet is `Lenovo` and uses `Biometric` device the you can use this `SDK`

[IBM Biometric software and SDK](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=pos1R4000256)

**NOTE** *The key is to find the correct device `SDK` and include it to your `C#` program.*